# Why is the second array one less then the first?

Tags: php

What is causing the second function to miss the last item of the second array?

```
$x = array(
  'Mon Sep 12 12:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Tue Sep 13 14:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Wed Sep 14 01:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Thu Sep 15 07:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Fri Sep 16 16:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Fri Sep 16 19:19:33 +0000 2011',
  'Sat Sep 17 15:57:37 +0000 2011',
  'Sun Sep 18 13:01:39 +0000 2011', 
  'id' => array('a','b')
);

//Create function to turn timestamps into unix timestamps so
function textTimeToUnixTime($x) {
  $z = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < count($x) - 1; $i++) {
    array_push($z, strtotime($x[$i]));
  }
  return $z;
}

function timeDifference($x)  {
  //Get Time Difference of the timestamps
  array_reverse($x);
  $z = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < count($x) - 1; $i++) {
    $a = $x[$i+1] - $x[$i];
    array_push($z, $a);
  }
  return $z;
}
```

Output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=> int(1315829973) 
  [1]=> int(1315923573) 
  [2]=> int(1315963173) 
  [3]=> int(1316071173) 
  [4]=> int(1316189973) 
  [5]=> int(1316200773) 
  [6]=> int(1316275057) 
  [7]=> int(1316350899)
} 

array(7) {
  [0]=> int(93600) 
  [1]=> int(39600) 
  [2]=> int(108000) 
  [3]=> int(118800) 
  [4]=> int(10800) 
  [5]=> int(74284) 
  [6]=> int(75842)
}
```

Comment: What good is the output formatted as two paragraphs of text?

Comment: I'm more surprised that the first function creates an array with 8 elements. The output of the second function makes more sense, as `$i` is at max the array length - 2

Comment: For me this code returns 2 arrays of size 8 and warning. Why don't you use `foreach` instead?

Comment: @felix I'm not. There's 8 to begin with. There's two [Friday](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zzfQwXEqYaI)s, then there's the weekend, weekend...

Comment: @adlawson: But in the first function, `$i` takes the values `0` to `count($x) - 2` which is `6`... makes 7 entries, not 8. Or am I missing something obvious? (I'm ignoring the `'id' => array('a','b')` entry btw, that does not seem to make sense at all).

Comment: @felix I see `count($x) - 1` which would make `$i == 7`, but who knows... `foreach` should definitely be used instead.

Comment: @adlawson: But `$i < count($x) - 1`, meaning when `$i` is `7`, the condition is not fulfilled (`7 < 7` is `false`) and the loop stops. Hence the loop only performs seven iterations, not eight,  with `$i = 6` being the last value fulfilling the condition.

Comment: @felix Ah, you're right; `$i < 7` not `$i <= 7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in timeDifference the last loop it calls $x[7+1] but there's no such $x[8] but rather a $x['id'] so it only works until 7.

Anyway, if you're comparing one time with the next one, the ammount of differences should be 1 less than the ammount of times.